# How to update the cheapest item owned by someone in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

Let's say I have the following table in Postgres:

```
fruit

fruit_id   owner_id   fruit_price    notes
-------------------------------------------
   1          5            15         
   2          5            30
   3          5            20
   4          8            10
   5          8            80
```

I am looking for a way to update the cheapest fruit owned by someone.

That is, I am looking for an operation that would allow me to set the `notes` column for the cheapest fruit owned by an individual. So this should only ever update one row (updating multiple rows is fine if there are several ties for the smallest value).

For example (psuedocode):

```
UPDATE fruit SET notes = 'wow cheap' WHERE owner_id = 5 AND fruit_price IS cheapest;
```

And this would update the first row in the above example data, because `fruit_id` of `1` is the cheapest fruit owned by user `5`.

Comment: What if user 5 had two rows with price = 15?

Comment: @Stu In that case then it would be fine to update both rows

Comment: If the answer by @Stu resolved your issue then you should accept it. If it does not answer it then what remains or why does it not resolve it. Accepting as answer aids future questioners having the same/similar issues and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is simply to use a correlated subquery:

```
update fruit set
  notes = 'some notes'
where owner_id = 5
  and fruit_price = (
    select min(fruit_price) from fruit f2 
    where f2.owner_id = fruit.owner_id
  );
```